# Retreive data from web to vb.net using syntax html

Tags: php, html, vb.net

I have an application for my school. I want to ask how to put on the web to my vb.net application .. on my links page, I use a string like this in php

```
example.com/school=directory_&nameemail=example@example.com
```

then in the html page, I want to take a special class that I want to unite with vb.net application to take the class "graduate" and its html syntax like this

```
<Div id = "headerSection"> <h2> Graduated </ h2>
```

how to retrieve data from the html syntax using vb.net, his example when I enter the email `example@example.com` on the `textbox1.text` issued a message "Graduated" ?

Thankyou
I hope anyone can help me
sorry for my bad english.